# Cassandra Row-level access control on non-partition key

Tags: cassandra

Is there any way of getting Row level access control on non-partition key from Cassandra?

For instance, RLAC (Row-level access control) is possible on partition key as seen in the below link:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secRlac.html

Is there any suggestion to this problem?

Comment: short answer - no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is no way to do that on Cassandra side, the column must be a partition key, maybe you can find solution using ACLs on application side. 
I hope this help !